# Character count with Dom Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can have string parameters like these to my function.

```
"Hello World <a>This is Link</a>"
"<span> Hello World </span><a>This is Link</a>"
"Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>"
```

I want to get character count of the text by not including dom elements tags.(`like <a> or <br>`)I only want character count.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Create a temporary element, add a string as `innerHTML`, and count the characters from `textContent`.

Answer (score 2):

this is it

```js
mstring = "Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>";
cleanText = mstring.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
console.log(cleanText.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/<[^>]*>/g` to find all the tags. Try the following way (space not counted):

```js
var str1 = "Hello World <a>This is Link</a>";
var str2 = "<span> Hello World </span><a>This is Link</a>";
var str3 = "Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>";

function getCharLen(str){
  str = str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "").split('').filter(i=>i!=' ');
  return str.length;
}

console.log(getCharLen(str1));
console.log(getCharLen(str2));
console.log(getCharLen(str3));
```

**OR:** If you want the spaces to be counted:

```js
var str1 = "Hello World <a>This is Link</a>";
var str2 = "<span> Hello World </span><a>This is Link</a>";
var str3 = "Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>";

function getCharLen(str){
  str = str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
  return str.length;
}

console.log(getCharLen(str1));
console.log(getCharLen(str2));
console.log(getCharLen(str3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the string into a node and get the length of `textConent` attribute.

```js
(function () {
    var node = document.createElement('pre');
    window.getCharCount = function (html) {
        node.innerHTML = html;
        return node.textContent.length;
        // return node.textContent.trim().length;   // if you want to ignore spaces at beginning and end
    };
}());

console.log(getCharCount('Hello World <a>This is Link</a>'));
console.log(getCharCount('<span> Hello World </span><a>This is Link</a>'));
console.log(getCharCount('Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex: `/(<\/?\w+>)/ig`

- start with `<`
- optional slash for end tags `\/?`
- any word character(s) `\w+`
- end with `>`
- modifier `ig` for global and case insensitive

You will get all the opening and closing tags. Just make them empty using replace and count the length of the rest of the string.

```js
function count(str) {
  var regex = /(<\/?\w+>)/ig;
  return str.replace(regex, '').length;
}


/* Test */

var a = "Hello World <a>This is Link</a>";
var b = "<span> Hello World </span><a>This is Link</a>";
var c = "Hello <br> World <a>This is Link</a>";

console.log(count(a));
console.log(count(b));
console.log(count(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp based solution:

```js
function removeHtmlTags (htmlString) {
  return htmlString
    .replace(/(<{1}[^>]*>)?/g, "")
    .replace(/(<\/{1}[^>]*>)?/g, "");
}
```